# My graphs using "as.layer()" no longer work

Tags: r, plot, graph, lattice

My code was working great but now it says it can't find the function "as.layer()" which is was using before.  I try to reload library(latticeExtra) but now the Error that I get is:

Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘latticeExtra’ in library.dynam(lib, package, package.lib):
DLL ‘png’ not found: maybe not installed for this architecture?

I have cleared all my packages, reinstalled them, updated to the latest version of everything but for some reason it won't let me load ‘latticeExtra’ any longer.

Thank you

Comment: Are you able to install the png package?

Comment: Yes, I installed the png package and installed, it slightly changed my error code now it says DLL 'jpeg' not found

Comment: Try re-installing the jpeg package and all other packages that latticeExtra depends on.

Comment: You are a hero, that was what I needed, thank you so much.  So I don't struggle with this in the future, how do you know what other packages a package depends on?  I don't recall installing the other two packages, I didn't even know they were packages until you asked the question.

Comment: `packageDescription("latticeExtra")` although there could be dependencies of dependencies too.

Comment: I can't tell you how much I appreciate you explaining this to me, I spent hours trying to work this out.  There is no way I would have thought to look for these libraries without your help.  You are the best of good men!